How to output x-value to given y-value of a previously fitted function?
I have fitted data (from a pandas dataframe) to a function
def cutoff(x, A):
    ff = 1/(1+(2 * np.pi * A * x)**2)**0.5
    return  ff
                     
xdata = data["X"]
ydata = data["CH1"]
popt, pcov=scipy.optimize.curve_fit(cutoff,xdata,ydata , p0 = [0.1e-3])

Now I want to output the x-value, where the y-value of the fit equals 1/2**0.5
I have no idea how to do this. Help would be much appreciated.
I didn't include my previous attempts, as they were all just wild guesses / copied code I didn't understand.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It seems that you have some x, y data and you wanna fit a curve on your data, based a cutoff function.
I made some modifications to your code that are as follows:
Code
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize


def cutoff(x, A):
    ff = 1 / (1 + (2 * np.pi * A * x) ** 2) ** 0.5
    return ff


def combined_function(x, A, B, C):
    return np.sin(x) * cutoff(x, A) + B * cutoff(x, C)


def find_x_value(A, B, C):
    return scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda x: combined_function(x, A, B, C) - 1 / np.sqrt(2), 0)


def gen_random():
    np.random.seed(10)
    xdata = np.linspace(1, 10, 100)
    ydata = np.sin(xdata) + np.random.normal(1, 0.1, size=len(xdata))
    return xdata, ydata


xdata, ydata = gen_random()
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(combined_function, xdata, ydata, p0=[0.1e-3, 1, 0.1e-3])

print(f"The x-value is {find_x_value(*popt)}")

Prints
The x-value is [-0.31678522]
Notes:

You don't need the gen_random() method.

Instead you need to pass your own x and y data.

p0 is the "initial guess for the parameters (length N). If None, then the initial values will all be 1 (if the number of parameters for the function can be determined using introspection, otherwise a ValueError is raised). See here.

scipy.optimize.fsolve: "Finds the roots of a function." Returns the roots of the equations defined, given a starting estimate. See here.

combined_function(x, A, B, C) is a combination of a sinusoidal function and your cutoff function. Note that B * cutoff(x, C) is nothing, but a linear addition to the combined function.




I can guess from your coding style that you use to code in MATLAB, and now you're coding in Python, most likely. Python has some best practices "rules", which I may not be following all in here, but it is recommend to do so. See here.


Don't do this. fsolve should not be used when the analytic inverse is trivial.

Don't use fsolve. Find the inverse analytically:
import numpy as np
import scipy


def cutoff(x: np.ndarray, a: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return 1 / np.sqrt(1 + (2*np.pi * a*x)**2)


def cutoff_inv(y: float, a: float) -> float:
    return np.sqrt((1/y)**2 - 1)/(2*np.pi*a)


rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
a_ideal = 1e-4
x = np.linspace(0, 1/a_ideal, num=101)
noise = rand.uniform(low=0.9, high=1.1, size=x.size)
ch1 = cutoff(x=x, a=a_ideal) * noise

(a,), _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(
    f=cutoff, xdata=x, ydata=ch1, p0=(1e-4,),
)
print(f'a = {a:.3e} ~ {a_ideal:.1e}')
y = np.sqrt(0.5)
xinv = cutoff_inv(y=y, a=a)
print(f'f({xinv:.2f}) = {cutoff(x=xinv, a=a):.4f} = {y:.4f}')

a = 9.911e-05 ~ 1.0e-04
f(1605.87) = 0.7071 = 0.7071

